# Spring Boot Annotation Autowired doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a problem with the @Autowired, i show u the error and the code :

Error :
[image]

Service :
[image]

Repository :
[image]

Pom :
[image]

Main :
[image]

can you help me please :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post code as images as those are totally unreadable. Please post code as code (thats is what code tags are for). When posting cod please include the package declarations as those are important. Finally ditch the `@Repository` on the interface as that is useless.

Comment: I guess, since you exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` in your Application.class, no `DataSource` is generated, hence no `Repositories` can be instanciated.

Comment: For the next i will post the code ty. But not we need to put @Repository it's not the good answer. jAC ok i will try

Comment: Thank you jAC, it was the DataSourceAutoConfiguration that blocked me

Comment: Consider adding the explanation as an answer and accept it so that your question can be "closed" and others benefit from it. Thanks ;)

Comment: @JoãoDias I added the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class` in your `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {...}` annotation.
This leads to Spring not instantiating/creating any beans for a database connectivity.

From the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration.html):

> Auto-configuration for DataSource.
> Enable auto-configuration of the Spring Application Context, attempting to **guess and configure beans** that you are likely to need.

In this case your `DataSource`:

> Attempts to establish a connection with the data source that this DataSource object represents.

Since `Repository` annotations require a database connectivity, their beans cannot be instantiated since no `DataSource` beans can be found.
This leads to your issues of `Repository` beans not being available.